# GLSL: Count of fragment shader 'out's

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I am trying to write a class that handles glsl and automatically gathers the number of:

- in(to vertex)/attributes
- uniforms
- out(from fragment)

I know how to get the count of the first 2 using openGL's api but I cannot find a method for the third. If there is a way using openGL, I would prefer to use that. Otherwise I'll use a grep-like method to scan the frag program and return the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [glGetProgramInterfaceiv()](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramInterface).  Something like this:

```
GLint numActiveOutputs = 0;
glGetProgramInterfaceiv(prog, GL_PROGRAM_OUTPUT​, GL_ACTIVE_RESOURCES​, &numActiveOutputs );
```

Comment: Awesome! Thats exactly what I was looking for!